# Maven install task seems to run tests on old code before compiling

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

1. Presume I have a working codebase. At this point running `mvn install` from Intellij idea works fine
2. Say I break one of my tests by adding `assertTrue(false)` to one of them
3. Now I run `maven install` and it outputs `Results: Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0` and then says `BUILD SUCCESS!`
4. Now however, if I run `maven install` again, I get the output `[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`

Same happens in reverse too. So if I now remove the `assertTrue(false)` from one of my tests, doing `mvn install` still triggers an error saying the tests failed but if I run it once more, it succeeds.

Is not really normal behavior or am I doing something wrong? I don't have a lot of experience with Maven nor JUnit.

My workflow has always been to just run `maven install` once and it installs it locally so my other projects can have it as a dependency and I get an outputted and minimised jar in the target folder.

I just added JUnit Jupiter and Surefire. This is my `pom.xml`: https://gist.github.com/VapidLinus/63103122483cb53ee9a534c229fbd72f

**Edit:** This only seems to be a problem if I change something in the *tests*. If I break the actual implementation of what the tests are testing, `mvn install` detects the problem on the first run.

Comment: Instead of running `mvn install` run `mvn clean install` in intellij idea and check. It will be better if you run in command prompt.

Comment: Based on the posted Gist I see several issues with your pom file: Having a plugin as a dependency is simply wrong..Using includes in maven-surefire violates the convention over configuration paradigm (follow naming conventions: `*Test.java` for unit tests..).To use JUnit Jupiter you have to add the junit-jupiter-engine dependency instead of JUnit Jupiter...you should also upgrade the maven-compiler-plugin which might cause the issue you are describing ...

Comment: Thanks for the advice @khmarbaise! I am still new to Maven so there's a lot I don't know or understand yet. Not sure what you mean with having a plugin as a dependency being wrong, you mean my other Spigot plugin? I couldn't get Maven to run my tests unless I had an include but I changed it to `<include>**/*Test.java</include>` now instead which also works. From the guides/tutorials I read, they only added JUnit Jupiter as a dependency and it seems to work - what's wrong with doing it this way? I will update my maven compiler plugin :) Thanks again, always trying to learn and improve

Comment: I meant that you have maven-surefire-plugin in your dependency area. Also the usage of dependencies with classifier `sources` or `javadoc` does not make sense...cause they can't be used on the classpath....

Comment: @VapidLinus, have you tried the suggestions made by @Deb? So that it can be clearly told whether it is Idea, or only Maven related problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run `mvn install -DskipTests`

A definitive solution would be to disable it on Surefire project configuration.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

[Reference](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html)

Comment: -DskipTests is great for improving compilation speed during development. But the question admonishes thet the _first_ testing seems on old test code. An other problem.

Comment: What does `skipTests` do? I am not sure I want to skip doing my tests. I just want the compilation to fail reliably when I break something and the tests should catch it